# How to calculate the Revenue growth with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the revenue growth for a set of companies.

My Data basically looks like this:

```
    Year    Name                Sales   Revenue Growth
0   2010.0  SHUTTERSTOCK INC    829730.0    0
1   2011.0  SHUTTERSTOCK INC    1202710.0   0
2   2012.0  SHUTTERSTOCK INC    1696160.0   0
3   2013.0  SHUTTERSTOCK INC    2355150.0   0
4   2014.0  SHUTTERSTOCK INC    3279710.0   0
```

The formula for Revenue Growth is (Sales t - Sales t-1) / sales (t-1). t and t-1 are only referring to the time indices. Can anyone help me how to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `pandas.Series.shift`. Lots of questions on SO rely on `shift`.

Comment: `df.Sales/df.Sale.shift() - 1`.

Comment: Great, thank guys!

Answer (score 2):

There is useful function `pct_change()` to do this:

```
df['Revenue Growth'] = df.Sales.pct_change()
```

result:

```
     Year              Name      Sales  Revenue Growth
0  2010.0  SHUTTERSTOCK INC   829730.0             NaN
1  2011.0  SHUTTERSTOCK INC  1202710.0        0.449520
2  2012.0  SHUTTERSTOCK INC  1696160.0        0.410282
3  2013.0  SHUTTERSTOCK INC  2355150.0        0.388519
4  2014.0  SHUTTERSTOCK INC  3279710.0        0.392569
```

It translates to: `df.Sales/df.Sales.shift() - 1`.